# How to compare 2 columns of 2 different tables on Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I did something like this with PHP and it works.

```
$table1 = $DB->query('SELECT column1 FROM table1');
$table2 = $DB->query('SELECT column2 FROM table2'); # excludes

$diff = "'" . implode("','", array_diff($table1, $table2)) . "'";

$DB->query("DELETE FROM table1 WHERE column1 IN ({$diff})");
```

My question is how to do the same with one sql statement, instead of writing 3 different and doing the `array_diff/implode` thing.

Unfortunately I have limited sql knowledge but I'm pretty sure it's possible, I think with `JOIN` but after 2 hours still can't find how. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sub-query. The query will be like below.

```
Delete from Table1 
where column1 in (
   SELECT column2 FROM table2
)
```

Comment: yes! that's exactly what I was looking for. thnx a million!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DELETE t1 
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.column1 = t2.column2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE column1 IN (
SELECT t0.column1 FROM
(SELECT column1 FROM table1) AS t0
JOIN
(SELECT column2 FROM table2) AS t1
ON t0.column1 = t1.column2)
```

Thanks.